# Notifications system for User into ManytoMany field

Tags: django

I got an issue I was wondering is there is a way to send a notification from Many to Many to each new user who are integrated to Reservation (notification has to be sent only to new users who belongs to `friends`). At the Reservation creation, `friends` == Null and then admin can add some user.

Does anyone has an idea about how I can manage to do it?

Assume `user` == reservation admin and `friends` are user who can only have access to the reservation.

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='friends_reservation')


def notifs_reservation(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    reservation = instance
    sender = reservation.user
    n_seller = reservation.friends
    notify = Notification(reservation=reservation, sender=sender, user=n_seller, notification_type=7)
    notify.save()
    
    send_mail(
        subject = "Lorem",
        message = render_to_string('notifs_reservation.html', {
                'sender': reservation.user,
                'n_userb': n_seller,
                'channel': reservation.slug,
            }),
        from_email="example@example.co",
        recipient_list=[n_seller.email]
    )

post_save.connect(notifs_reservation, sender=Reservation)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sending notifications" ?

Comment: I mean one by one, assume I add X and then 10mn later Y. I don't want to receive again a notif if I add Y :)

Comment: Add a through table to your M2M relationship that has a boolean field. Then when you add someone, check you already add someone for that reservation and if not, then send a notification. Maybe i did not understand fully your problem if that does not help.